# How to save data if you have two HABTM relations in a single model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have altogether three models: User, Album and Genre. User refers to artist(singer, compose, musician etc). An album can have many artists(users) and many genres. An artist can compose/sing for many albums.In short I have following models and controller action . **I have created two HABTM relations: albums_genres and users_albums in db.**

```
//User model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :albums
end

//Album model
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

//Genre model
 class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :albums
 end

//albumController create method
def create
  @user = current_user
  @album = @user.albums.new(params[:album])
  if @album.save
     ...
  end
end
```

When I send data as follows, data is inserted properly in albums_users.

```
"Album"=>{"title"=>"Test album", "description"=>"test description"
```

However I want insert data into albums_genres table as well. For this, my params data looks like:

```
"Album"=>{"title"=>"Test album", "description"=>"test description", "genre_ids"=>["1", "2", "3"]}
```

Then I got an error **Can't mass-assign protected attributes: genre_ids**. It's trying to insert data into albums table which I believe should insert genre_ids into albums_genres. So my question is how do i need to write controller code? Better way to write controller and/or model code is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance! Reference taken from: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

Comment: pasting error on first params data? I see no reference to user.

Comment: There is:   `@user = current_user` . It didn't work when I wrote as 
`@album = current_user.albums.new(params[:album])`. So I had to change like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `genre_ids` to you mass assignable attributes:

```
attr_accessible :genre_ids
```

then your data creates the record in `albums_genres`.

In your `Album` you get the collections `genres` and `genre_ids`. The first holds an array of `Genre` objects, the second an array of just the `id`s of the genres.
You can add or assign to both of these arrays, to manage the assocciation.
Mass assignment just sets the `genre_ids` but needs explicit permission for that (mass assignment restrictions).

Comment: On top of this, put your `current_user.id` as a `hidden_field` in your form, it's messy code to be saving a `User` in your `AlbumsController#create` action (`hidden_field_tag "user_ids[]", current_user.id`)